# Jquery datepiker overlaps by div

Tags: jquery, css, datepicker, overlap

pls help.
I added datepicker from jquery default library.
But some  with  overlap it when it is open.
Customize css?
Thanks to all...

[opened datepicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsHeP.png)
[closed datepicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/co9Ql.png)

Comment: Please add your actual code here in the question so that the question is still of value when those images go away. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the background color of the picker to white or you can use an 1 pixel white image for the background which will repeat and fill the datepicker div

for example if your div has a css class say `ui-datepicker`

Then you can use the below css

```
 .ui-datepicker{
     background-color: #ffffff;
 }
```

I assumed the class as `ui-datepicker` you need to find the css class by yourself

in jQueryUI the CSS class usually will be `ui-datepicker`

I would imagine that you have bootstrap css and jquery css mixed together, if that is the case

Then, re-order the CSS inclusion and make the jQueryUI CSS appear last

If the buttons are not clickable then the z-Index is overridden by another div tag

change the `z-index`

```
.ui-datepicker{
  z-index: 99999;
}
```

Comment: Ty for answer, but I cant push a datepicker buttons through the div, its another kind of trouble, i think.

Comment: I added one more solution for z-index